# Is there an operation which block diagonalizes a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, block-matrices

Suppose $M$ is an $2n \times 2n$ block matrix:
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A,B,C$ and $D$ are square matrices of the same order. Are there operations that block-diagonalizes $M$:
$$M \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & D 
\end{pmatrix}
?
$$
What about anti-block diagonalize:
$$M \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
0 & B \\
C & 0
\end{pmatrix}?
$$

We can assume $n \ge 2$ here. If such operations do not exist for *every* matrix, do these exist for particular matrices (i.e. symmetric, anti-symmetric, and so on)?

**EDIT:** Such transformations could be, say, a product $SMS$ or $SM S^{-1}$ that does the job, or something related. In other words, can we find other matrices whose products give the block diagonalized or anti-block diagonalized $M$ (i.e. some sort of "projection")?

Comment: What happens when $n=1$?

Comment: @saulspatz In this case we take $A,B,C,D$ to be numbers.

Comment: Yes, but not every $2\times2$ matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Oh, okay. But what about $n \ge 2$ then? I'm not interested in the case $n =1$ anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly: as written, those operations just take a matrix and change a bunch of entries to zero. Of course you can define those operations, but why would you? If the $A$ in $M=(\begin{smallmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{smallmatrix})$ is not the same as the $A$ in "$M\mapsto(\begin{smallmatrix}A&0\\0&D\end{smallmatrix})$", you should clarify that and explain how $M$ and the "block diagonalized $M$" relate. Are you looking for a change of basis, as is the case for usual diagonalization?

Comment: I edited the post to be inclusive $n \ge 2$ and also allow for particular choice of matrices too.

Comment: Please clarify if the $A$ in $M$ is the same $A$ as in the image of $M$ under your transformation, or if that could be a different block. Also could you please give a little motivation why you are interested in this? It looks like a rather arbitrary question. (Please edit your post instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $I$ the $n\times n$ identity matrix and define block matrices
$$
\mathbf E_{11} = \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\ 
\mathbf E_{12} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & I \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\ 
\mathbf E_{21} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ I & 0\end{pmatrix},\ 
\mathbf E_{22} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Note that for $M=(\begin{smallmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end{smallmatrix})$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbf E_{11} M \mathbf E_{11} &= \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},
& 
\mathbf E_{11} M \mathbf E_{22} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & B \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \\
\mathbf E_{22} M \mathbf E_{11} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ C & 0\end{pmatrix},
& 
\mathbf E_{22} M \mathbf E_{22} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & D\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence, you can construct your projections as
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & D\end{pmatrix} = \mathbf E_{11} M \mathbf E_{11} + \mathbf E_{22} M \mathbf E_{22}, \\
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & B \\ C & 0\end{pmatrix} = \mathbf E_{11} M \mathbf E_{22} + \mathbf E_{22} M \mathbf E_{11}.
\end{align}

Comment: Christoph, thanks! That was what I was expecting. Do these relations have any direct interpretation (for instace, some projection into some subspace)?

Comment: They are projections onto the subspace of block matrices of that form, sure.